# Wildfly no Start on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly

I download Wildfly 8.1 and put in Servers for Netbeans 8.0. I did not modify anything in the Wildfly and when I run this server by netbeans this error appears:

```
[2015-07-16 10:07:06,674] Artifact sapre:war: java.lang.Exception: 
{"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => 
["jboss.deployment.unit.\"sapre.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing 
[jboss.deployment.unit.\"sapre.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.ejb3.dd-based-ejb-
    client-context.\"sapre.war\" is missing 
[jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem.outbound-connection.remote-ejb-connection]"]}
```

I put the postgres driver in \standalone\deployments but it's not working.

My standalone.xml file is so large to put here.

Please, help-me.

Comment: Please show configuration file (suppose, standalone.xml). I'm interesting in row number 3. Can you show first several lines?

Comment: In row number 3 we have: <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">

Comment: You have changed wildfly log in question. You caught another error?

Comment: Yes, that erros not more appears